# how to upload an image to folder src/assets in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

how to upload images to the src/assets folder in vuejs because now I want to upload it to my desired folder to test before I can use a real server.
Please help me to solve this problem.
I want to upload the version to the folder and upload it to the API server.

```
<label
    class="imagePreviewWrapper"
    style="cursor: pointer"
    for="file"
>
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <input
            ref="fileInput"
            type="file"
            id="file"
            @change="uploadFile"
            style="display: none"
            accept=".jpg"
        />
        <img :src="previewImageUrl" alt="Preview Image" />
        <i class="bi bi-camera icon"></i>
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: `I want to upload version to folder` what does version mean here? You'll need server side code to handle the upload

Answer (score 0):

You can't. the thing about SPA is that your code runs on the browser. So you need server to do something like that.

The solution is just send your file to your server and let them handle the upload

Answer (score 0):

As I know you cannot upload something dynamically for src/assets folder. because it uses to save assets for development. you have to create some folder or if you using firebase like service then you want to add firebase storage like service as well. because src/assets folder is rendering when building the vue application. so after building vue app there are no more src/assets folder.